# jQuery: Removing HTML-element while keeping it's children

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to add HTML like this:

```
<div><img src="item.png"/>&nbsp;<a href="#"><span>Hello</span></a></div>
```

but in some cases I need to get rid of the wrapping a-element, so it looks like this:

```
<div><img src="item.png"/>&nbsp;<span>Hello</span></div>
```

This a-element could be anywhere in arbitrary HTML-fragments. I grab it by a[href="#"]. This HTML is not part of the DOM, it get's added to the DOM after the a-element was removed.

I went to all kind of stuff jQuery offers for this, but didn't make it. My main problem is,
that there seems to be no way to apply a selector to HTML created by jQuery like this:

```
$("html code from above");
```

I tried to get the a-element replacing it with it's inner HTML, but all my constructs with
find() and replaceWith() fail, mostly just the `<span>Hello</span>` is left :(

How does a jQuery-pro solve this?

Comment: Instead of removing the anchor, why not add it if needed?

Comment: The a-element forms the clickable part of the HTML and as this is created by "third party" I wouldn't know where to put it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is set the context of your selector.  See this reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context

In your case, when you do the selection to replace the link, set the context as the HTML fragment that you are modifying.  Here's an example:

```
$(function() {
    //create snippet
    var mySnippet = $('<div><img src="item.png"/>&nbsp;<a href="#"><span>Hello</span></a></div>');

    //remove the link, using the snippet as the context
    $('a[href="#"]', mySnippet).replaceWith($('a[href="#"]', mySnippet).html());

    //insert the modified snippet
    $('body').append(mySnippet);
});
```

And here's a demo of that in action (not very exciting, but shows that it works): http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/dQ32B/

Comment: Thanks Ender, this works fine. I wasn't aware of the possibility to give a context when using replaceWith.

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't the **[unwrap](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)** feature do what you want?

If you just want to remove the surrounding tag (like an anchor)

Comment: Just wanted to add that if you have text in an element you wan't to unwrap, you have to chain contents first: $('a').contents().unwrap()